# lanching desktop application in containers and making them accessible like services using kubernetes and xorg

Tags: kubernetes, containers, desktop, xorg, xserver

In a school project, we've been asked to solve the following problem:
our students use some software (desktop application )for their studies like packet-tracer, eclipseIDE, qjis, etc. and they may have problems of performance with their PCs or version incompatibilities when sharing project files.

The idea is to not let the students worry about installing these apps on their PCs, but they can connect to school server and the the app will be open directly on their PCs although the app will run inside a container in the server but its UI will be forwarded to student pc using xforwarding or xorg.

server will have kubernetes to manage containers running these desktop apps in containers and provide them  as services or let's say like RDP running app but in this case container running app.

Can we manage to do this, if so what would be the architecture, and how will manage to keep the connection between the PC and the same container running the application?

To explain more the challenge, regular kubernetes use case like microservices, expose containerized application through services
it doesn't matter which container that handle your request, loadbalancer usually use roundrobin to choose which container it forwards the request.

but in our case we must treat a container like rdp a user must keep connection to the same container because it is running a desktop app like eclipse.

Comment: You may want to look at the kubevirt project (https://kubevirt.io/)

Comment: kubevirt.io let you manage VMs like containers using k8s, but in my situation, that may be ressources consuiming, I think I can run the app in containers(in server), and forward app UI from the container to user pc but how do I keep the connection between the same  container and pc

in web app for exemples a user request can be handeled by any  container
in my case a user must work with same container like remote dektop

Comment: Kubevirt sits on top of Kubernetes and lets you run containers containing qemu-like VMs. It's been a while since I played with it, but I was able to run a full linux desktop environment using it.